# I want to use a DStream later but it is getting empty till then, how to resolve this?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am newbie in Spark Streaming and for a job my input is from kafka and I process that input and after processing I save one DStream(say "history" stream) which I got after filtering final DStream after processing. I cache this DStream then and in the next batch union this DStream with my input DStream and perform same processing as earlier , when I obsereved that till the time union the "history" DStream is empty.Kindly tell a way resolve this problem.

Comment: could you add the code to the question to make it clear? Also, next to 'what you are doing', also clarify 'what you are trying to achieve'

Comment: Hey I have posted the same question with whole code this time and given possible explaination about what I want to achieve , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434675/not-able-to-persist-the-dstream-for-use-in-further-future-use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to persist the DStream for use in next batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434675/not-able-to-persist-the-dstream-for-use-in-next-batch)