# Not able to persist the DStream for use in next batch

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, dstream

```
JavaRDD<String> history_ = sc.emptyRDD();

java.util.Queue<JavaRDD<String> > queue = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>();
queue.add(history_);
JavaDStream<String> history_dstream = ssc.queueStream(queue);

JavaPairDStream<String,ArrayList<String>> history = history_dstream.mapToPair(r -> {
  return new Tuple2< String,ArrayList<String> >(null,null);
});  

 JavaPairInputDStream<String, GenericData.Record> stream_1 =
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class, GenericData.Record.class, StringDecoder.class,
        GenericDataRecordDecoder.class, props, topicsSet_1);


JavaPairInputDStream<String, GenericData.Record> stream_2 =
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class, GenericData.Record.class, StringDecoder.class,
        GenericDataRecordDecoder.class, props, topicsSet_2);
```

then doing some transformation and creating twp DStream Data_1 and Data_2 of type

```
JavaPairDStream<String, <ArrayList<String>>
```

and do the join as below , then filtering out those records for whom there was no joining key and saving them in history for using it in next batch by doing its union with Data_1

```
 Data_1 = Data_1.union(history);

JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<ArrayList<String>, Optional<ArrayList<String>>>> joined =
    Data_1.leftOuterJoin(Data_2).cache();


JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<ArrayList<String>, Optional<ArrayList<String>>>> notNULL_join = joined.filter(r -> r._2._2().isPresent());
JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<ArrayList<String>, Optional<ArrayList<String>>>> dstream_filtered = joined.filter(r -> !r._2._2().isPresent());

history = dstream_filtered.mapToPair(r -> {
  return new Tuple2<>(r._1,r._2._1);
}).persist;
```

I get history after the previous step(checked by saving it to hdfs) , but still this history is empty in batch while doing union.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, what you would like to achieve is to keep a history of records of elements of `Data1` not yet found in `Data2` until they are found. Is that right? Any other additional requirement? What's the usecase?

Comment: Yes that's it, now what you suggest

Comment: No additional requirements , use case is to find click count by user using join on pageview and click events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's conceptually not possible to "remember" a `DStream`. `DStreams` are time-bound and on each clock-tick (called "batch interval") the `DStream` *represents* the observed data in the stream during that period of time.

Hence, we cannot have an "old" `DStream` saved to join with a "new" `DStream`. All `DStreams` live in the "now".

The underlying data structure of `DStreams` is the `RDD`: Each batch interval, our `DStream` will have 1 `RDD` of the data for that interval.
`RDD`s represent a distributed collection of data. `RDD`s are immutable and permanent, for as long as we have a reference to them.

We can combine `RDD`s and `DStream`s to create the "history roll over" that's required here.

It looks pretty similar to the approach on the question, but only using the `history` `RDD`.

Here's a high-level view of the suggested changes:

```
var history: RDD[(String, List[String]) = sc.emptyRDD()

val dstream1 = ...
val dstream2 = ...

val historyDStream = dstream1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(history))
val joined = historyDStream.join(dstream2)

... do stuff with joined as above, obtain dstreamFiltered ...

dstreamFiltered.foreachRDD{rdd =>
   val formatted = rdd.map{case (k,(v1,v2)) => (k,v1)} // get rid of the join info
   history.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
   history = formatted // assign the new history
   history.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
   history.count() //action to materialize this transformation
}
```

This is only a starting point. There're additional considerations with regards to `checkpoint`ing. Otherwise the lineage of the `history` RDD will grow unbounded until some StackOverflow happens. This blog is quite complete on this particular technique: http://www.spark.tc/stateful-spark-streaming-using-transform/

I also recommend you using Scala instead of Java. The Java syntax is too verbose to use with Spark Streaming.

Comment: @JSR29 it should be `formatted`. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: regarding how history builds up, it's intrinsically composed by unions of `RDD`s as consequence of this line: `dstream1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(history))`. That's why I mention that checkpoint is important. Otherwise, the lineage of that RDD will grow unbounded over time.

Comment: regarding java, you can probably get around with `final` requirement by using an array as mutable intermediate. In general, I find java a bad choice for use with Spark Streaming. The syntactical constructions are awful.

Comment: Can you tell something using the mapWithState

Comment: You could probably approach the click count usecase with `mapWithState`, but not in the approach of this question. Give it a try and ask new questions if those arise. StructuredStreaming is another option in the Spark family.

Comment: can I use a window of 24 hrs.

Comment: It's your choice to use java, not mine. ;-) Sorry, I won't go through that pain. Not even the programming guide does: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd

Comment: Thanks @maasg , this approach worked , I have to verify the results

Comment: Cool. As you productize the job, don't forget to add the `checkpoint`  function as explained in that blog. Otherwise, it will crash after some time (hours, days,?) or runtime.

Comment: Can you explain the building of history

Comment: @JSR29 Yes, I could, but I don't think it would fit into a comment. Care to open a new question?

Comment: here is the link of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482883/how-history-rdds-are-preserved-for-further-use-in-the-given-code

Comment: "RDD: Each batch interval, our DStream will have 1 RDD of the data for that interval" .  is that a assumption you are making

Comment: Why don't persist and cache didn't worked on filter DStream , remember also didn't worked