# How history RDDs are preserved for further use in the given code

Tags: spark-streaming

```
{
var history: RDD[(String, List[String]) = sc.emptyRDD()

val dstream1 = ...
val dstream2 = ...

val historyDStream = dstream1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(history))
val joined = historyDStream.join(dstream2)

... do stuff with joined as above, obtain dstreamFiltered ...

dstreamFiltered.foreachRDD{rdd =>
val formatted = rdd.map{case (k,(v1,v2)) => (k,v1) }
history.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
history = formatted // assign the new history
history.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
history.count() //action to materialize this transformation
}
```

This code logic is working fine for preserving all the previous RDDs which didn't successfully joined and saved for the future batches so that whenever we get a record with corresponding joining key for this RDD , we perform the join but I didn't got how this history is build up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can understand how the history builds up in this case by observing how the RDD lineage evolves over time.

We need two pieces of previous knowledge:

- RDDs are immutable structures
- Operations on RDD can be expressed in functional terms by the function to be applied and references to the input RDDs.

Let's see a quick example, using the classical wordCount:

```
val txt = sparkContext.textFile(someFile)
val words = txt.flatMap(_.split(" "))
```

In simplified terms, `txt` is a `HadoopRDD(someFile)`. `words` is a `MapPartitionsRDD(txt, flatMapFunction)`. We speak of the `lineage` of words as the DAG (Direct Acyclic Graph) that is formed of this chaining of operations.: `HadoopRDD <-- MapPartitionsRDD`.

We can apply the same principles to our streaming operation:

At iteration 0, we have

```
var history: RDD[(String, List[String]) = sc.emptyRDD()
// -> history: EmptyRDD
...
val historyDStream = dstream1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(history))
// -> underlying RDD: rdd.union(EmptyRDD)
join, filter
// underlying RDD: ((rdd.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD)).filter(pred)
map
// -> underlying RDD: ((rdd.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD)).filter(pred).map(f) 
history.unpersist(false)
//  EmptyRDD.unpersist (does nothing, it was never persisted)
history = formatted
// history =  ((rdd.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD)).filter(pred).map(f)
history.persist(...)
// history marked for persistence (at the next action)
history.count()
// ((rdd.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD)).filter(pred).map(f).count()
// cache result of:  ((rdd.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD)).filter(pred).map(f)
```

At iteration 1, we have (adding rdd0, rdd1 as iteration index):

```
val historyDStream = dstream1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(history))
// -> underlying RDD: rdd1.union(((rdd0.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD0)).filter(pred).map(f))
join, filter
// underlying RDD: ((rdd1.union(((rdd0.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD0)).filter(pred).map(f)).join(otherRDD1)).filter(pred)
map
// -> underlying RDD: ((rdd1.union(((rdd0.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD0)).filter(pred).map(f)).join(otherRDD1)).filter(pred).map(f) 
history.unpersist(false)
//  history0.unpersist (marks the previous result for removal, we used it already for our computation above)
history = formatted
// history1 =  ((rdd1.union(((rdd0.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD0)).filter(pred).map(f)).join(otherRDD1)).filter(pred).map(f)
history.persist(...)
// new history marked for persistence (at the next action)
history.count()
// ((rdd1.union(((rdd0.union(EmptyRDD).join(otherRDD0)).filter(pred).map(f)).join(otherRDD1)).filter(pred).map(f).count()
// cache result sothat we don't need to compute it next time
```

This iterative process goes on with each iteration.

As we can see, the graph representing the RDD computation keeps on growing. `cache` reduces the cost of making all calculations each time. `checkpoint` is needed every so often to write a concrete computed value of this growing graph so that we can use it as baseline instead of having to evaluate the whole chain.

An interesting way to see this process in action is by adding a line within the foreachRDD to inspect the current lineage:

```
...
history.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
history = formatted // assign the new history
println(history.toDebugString())
...
```

Comment: can you also help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492558/how-to-write-spark-streaming-output-to-hdfs-without-overwriting

Comment: @JSR29 don't get used to it :)

Comment: BTW, was the explanation clear? Did you understand how the history builds up over time?

Comment: We use checkpointing for getting the RDDs in case they lost , so we don't need recomputation , but what happens if we don't checkpoint and some RRDs are lost , would it show some Runtime Exception or what?

Comment: A DStream is a continous sequence of RDDs , it is not some single RDD , so when you are doing         history.unpersist   then history = formatted it would replace the previous RDD of same filtered DStream  , like if in filtered dstream has 2 rdds R1 AND R2 , so in first iteration , at the starting of block you will unpersist empty history then history = formatted(R1) then in next iteration of history(R1).unpersist and history=formatted(R2) , so we lost the R1

Comment: @JSR29 This assumption is incorrect: "dstream has 2 rdds R1 AND R2" A DStream represents a sequence of RDDs over time, but at any given time, there's only one RDD underlying the DStream (this is somehow different for window operations, but we only get to see a single RDD through the DStream interfaces).

Comment: thanks now this explaination is clear , I was confused as I knew that DStream at each interval is set of RDDs

Comment: what would be difference if we don't use history.count and after doing all computations there is a single action of saving result to HDFS , I tries this then observes that there is nothing in Storage section of the web UI

Comment: please answer the above question.