# How to write Spark Streaming output to HDFS without overwriting

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

After some processing I have a DStream[String , ArrayList[String]] , so when I am writing it to hdfs using saveAsTextFile and after every batch it overwrites the data , so how to write new result by appending to previous results

```
output.foreachRDD(r => {
  r.saveAsTextFile(path)
})
```

**Edit ::** If anyone could help me in converting the output to avro format and then writing to HDFS with appending

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017366/how-can-i-make-spark1-6-saveastextfile-to-append-existing-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`saveAsTextFile` does not support append. If called with a fixed filename, it will overwrite it every time.
We could do `saveAsTextFile(path+timestamp)` to save to a new file every time. That's the basic functionality of `DStream.saveAsTextFiles(path)`

An easily accessible format that supports `append` is Parquet. We first transform our data RDD to a `DataFrame` or `Dataset` and then we can benefit from the write support offered on top of that abstraction.

```
case class DataStructure(field1,..., fieldn)

... streaming setup, dstream declaration, ...

val structuredOutput = outputDStream.map(record => mapFunctionRecordToDataStructure)
structuredOutput.foreachRDD(rdd => 
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val df = rdd.toDF()
  df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save(s"$workDir/$targetFile")

})
```

Note that appending to Parquet files gets more expensive over time, so rotating the target file from time to time is still a requirement.

Comment: Any code for converting RDD[String , ArrayList] string to avro format , I have a schema.

Comment: The above code for appending is just creating new files for every batch ,it is not appending to the same file.

Comment: It's appending to the same logical file, but indeed creating small `part-xxxx` files in the filesystem. You can load all the data at once with `sparkSession.read.parquet(path)`. From Spark Streaming, I would recommend writing to a distributed database, such as Cassandra, instead than to the fs.

Comment: Kindly help me with this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524828/task-not-serializable-exception-when-trying-to-write-a-rdd-of-type-generic-recor

Comment: is there a way i can save the data for each spark streaming batch into a seprate file..i want something line "/rootpath/batch_id/filename" ?

Comment: Whats is the python version of the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the same file and store on file system, store it as a parquet file. You can do it by

```
  kafkaData.foreachRDD( rdd => {
  if(rdd.count()>0)
  {
    val df=rdd.toDF()
    df.write(SaveMode.Append).save("/path")
   }
```

Comment: then also it creates multiple files. @ishan Kumar

Comment: Did you test this? I think it adds new files into the /path directory

Answer (score 0):

Storing the streaming output to HDFS will always create a new files even in case when you use append with parquet which leads to a small files problems on Namenode. I may recommend to write your output to sequence files where you can keep appending to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Here I solve the issue without dataframe

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime

 messages.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
    rdd.repartition(1)
    val eachRdd = rdd.map(record => record.value)
    if(!eachRdd.isEmpty) {
      eachRdd.saveAsTextFile(hdfs_storage + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(LocalDateTime.now) + "/")
    }
  }
```