# Task Not Serializable exception when trying to write a rdd of type Generic Record

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, avro

```
val file = File.createTempFile("temp", ".avro")
val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(st)
val datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter[GenericData.Record](schema)
val dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter[GenericData.Record](datumWriter)
dataFileWriter.create(schema , file)
rdd.foreach(r => {
  dataFileWriter.append(r)
})
dataFileWriter.close()
```

I have a `DStream` of type `GenericData.Record` which I am trying to write to HDFS in the Avro format but I'm getting this `Task Not Serializable` error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2062)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:911)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:910)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:910)
at KafkaCo$$anonfun$main$3.apply(KafkaCo.scala:217)
at KafkaCo$$anonfun$main$3.apply(KafkaCo.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter, value: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter@78f132d9)
- field (class: KafkaCo$$anonfun$main$3$$anonfun$apply$1, name: dataFileWriter$1, type: class org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter)
- object (class KafkaCo$$anonfun$main$3$$anonfun$apply$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by writing the RDD object into an Avro file? You should take a loot at https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro which lets you save a DataFrame directly into Avro-formatted files using something like `df.write.avro("/tmp/output")`

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that the `DataFileWriter` is a local resource (bound to a local file), so serializing it does not make sense.

Adapting the code to do things like `mapPartitions` will not help either, as such executor-bound approach will write files on the local filesystem of the executors.

We need to use an implementation that supports the distributed nature of Spark, for example, https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

Using that library:

Given some schema represented by a `case class`, we would do:

```
val structuredRDD = rdd.map(record => recordToSchema(record))
val df = structuredRDD.toDF()
df.write.avro(hdfs_path)
```

Comment: what's recordToSchema

Comment: a function that you write to convert the record format to your case class.

Comment: any example can you provide as I haven't done this before

Comment: @JSR29 well, I see that `GenericData.Record` is already an AVRO format. Maybe there are smarter ways to directly save it as AVRO. - I don't know.

Comment: Does this work for streaming as well? The question metions `DStream`s.

Comment: @stefanobaghino sure, as long as the path is different on each streaming interval, like appending timestamp for example. Although this approach should work, I would think that there's an easier way to go from a `GenericData.Record` to an AVRO file.

Answer (score 1):

Since lambdas have to be distributed around the cluster for running, they have to only reference serializable data so that they can be serialized, shipped to different executors for deployment and executed there as tasks.

What you could probably do is:

- create a new file and obtain a handle to it
- use the `mapPartitions` (instead of `map`) method and create a new writer for each partition
- use the file handle with the writer you create for each partition to append each message within the partition to that file
- ensure the file handle is closed when the stream is fully consumed

Comment: Here where am I using map , and a psuedo code would be much helpful

Comment: Although valid advice in general, I don't think that `mapPartitions` and local objects will help in this case. Note how this `dataFileWriter` is bound to a local file:  `dataFileWriter.create(schema , file)`, Using `mapPartitions` we would create a local file on each executor.

Comment: That's why I suggested passing around a file handler to be closed when the stream is fully consumed and not the current mode of operating. Today I'll hopefully have time to edit my answer with some code.